# Динамические кнопки pytelegrambot

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Я самоучка-новичок, сильно не бейте за кривой код :).
Бьюсь уже 3ий день с проблемой. Хочу сделать динамические кнопки, что при нажатии на продукт, его кнопка моментально менялась(при call.data == edit_product) или моментально удалялась (при call.data == delete_product). При моей реализации клавиши удаляются или меняются только при выходе из меню по кнопке "назад" либо если отправить /show (т.е.показать список).

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['show'])
def show_products(message):
    if list_of_products:
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Редактировать ✏', callback_data='done')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить ', callback_data='delete')
        keyboard.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ('Список покупок:\n' + line_print(list_of_products)), reply_markup=keyboard)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Список пуст")
         
      
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'delete':
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            btns = []
            for product in list_of_products:
                btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{product}', callback_data=f'delete_product {product}')
                btns.append(btn)
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='back')
            btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Редактировать ✏', callback_data='edit')
            keyboard.add(*btns)
            keyboard.add(btn1, btn2)
            bot.edit_message_text('Какой продукт хотите удалить?', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                                  reply_markup=keyboard)
        elif call.data == 'edit':
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            btns = []
            for product in list_of_products:
                if '\u0336' in product:
                    btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'✖ {product}', callback_data=f'delete_product {product}')
                else:
                    btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{product}', callback_data=f'edit_product {product}')
                btns.append(btn)
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='back')
            btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить ', callback_data='delete')
            keyboard.add(*btns)
            keyboard.add(btn1, btn2)
            bot.edit_message_text('Какой продукт хотите вычеркнуть?', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                                  reply_markup=keyboard)
        elif call.data == 'back':
            if list_of_products:
                keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Редактировать ✏', callback_data='edit')
                btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить ', callback_data='delete')
                keyboard.add(btn1, btn2)
                bot.edit_message_text(line_print(list_of_products), call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                                      reply_markup=keyboard)
            else:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Список пуст")
        elif 'delete_product' in call.data:
            if list_of_products:
                product = call.data.split()[1]
                list_of_products.remove(product)
                # show alert
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text='Удалено')
                print(list_of_products)
            else:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Список пуст")

        elif 'edit_product' in call.data:
            product = call.data.split()[1]
            if '\u0336' in product:
                uncross_product(product, list_of_products)
                # show alert
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text='Отменил отметку')
            else:
                cross_product(product, list_of_products)
                # show alert
                bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text='Отметил, что купил')

        elif call.data == 'yes':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='Список удален',
                                  message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                  reply_markup=None)
            list_of_products.clear()
        elif call.data == 'no':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='А, ну хорошо...',
                                  message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                  reply_markup=None)
            show_products(call.message)


def line_print(grocery_list):
    new_line = ''
    for i, item in enumerate(grocery_list):
        new_line += (str(i + 1) + ') ' + item + '\n')
    return new_line


def cross_product(product, grocery_list):
    cross_product = ('\u0336'.join(product) + '\u0336')
    for i in range(len(grocery_list)):
        if grocery_list[i] == product:
            grocery_list[i] = cross_product


def uncross_product(cross_product, grocery_list):
    for i in range(len(grocery_list)):
        if grocery_list[i] == cross_product:
            grocery_list[i] = cross_product.replace('\u0336', '')
```

Comment: `btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Редактировать ✏', callback_data='done')` возможно тут должно быть `callback_data='edit'`?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это помогло мне решить другой баг :) (при первом открытии списка /show, некорректно работала кнопка "редактировать").
Вопрос "динамичности" кнопок остался в силе.

Answer (score 1):

```
def select_list():
    kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    kb.row_width = 2
    kb.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Симферополь', callback_data='simferopol'),
           InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ялта', callback_data='yalta'))
    return kb



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def inline_kb(call):
    if call.data == 'yalta':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Выберите место', reply_markup=kb_yalta())
```

Таким образом, при нажатии на кнопку "Ялта" сообщение будет изменено на "Выберите место" с добавлением клавиатуры `kb_yalta()`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Решил свою проблему топорным методом, после удаления, либо корректировки надписи на кнопке (вычеркивание из списка), после изменений формирую и вывожу новую клавиатуру. Не знаю на сколько это корректно, но вроде работает :)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся на мой вопрос. Решил проблему топорным методом: после удаления, либо корректировки надписи на кнопке (вычеркивание из списка) формирую и вывожу новую клавиатуру. Извиняюсь за гигантизм кода, пока руки не дошли до рефакторинга.

```
    elif 'delete_product' in call.data:
        if list_of_products:
            product = call.data.split()[1]
            list_of_products.remove(product)
            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text='Удалено')
            print(list_of_products)
        else:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Список пуст")

        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        products = []
        for product in list_of_products:
            if '\u0336' in product:
                btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'✖ {product}', callback_data=f'delete_product {product}')
            else:
                btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{product}', callback_data=f'delete_product {product}')
            products.append(btn)
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='back')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Редактировать ✏', callback_data='edit')
        keyboard.add(*products)
        keyboard.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                                      reply_markup=keyboard)

    elif 'edit_product' in call.data:
        product = call.data.split()[1]
        if '\u0336' in product:
            uncross_product(product, list_of_products)
            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text='Отменил отметку')
        else:
            cross_product(product, list_of_products)
            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text='Отметил, что купил')

        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        products = []
        for product in list_of_products:
            if '\u0336' in product:
                btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'✖ {product}', callback_data=f'edit_product {product}')
            else:
                btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{product}', callback_data=f'edit_product {product}')
            products.append(btn)
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='back')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить ', callback_data='delete')
        keyboard.add(*products)
        keyboard.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                                      reply_markup=keyboard)
```